# bigQuery throws "division by zero: 0 / 0" error

Tags: sql, select, group-by, count, google-bigquery

I am doing the percentage by the frequency of column value using bigquery. However, some of the value might be zero, so the query will return error for sure

```
(division by zero: 0 / 0)
```

How to apply kind of IFERROR(x/y,null) in this case? so the query will bounce null value as the result instead of error?

```
SELECT 
    User_ID, 
   ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%MIKE%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(Name) * 100 ,1) AS Percentage_of_MIKE,
    
FROM
  table
GROUP BY 
  User_ID
```

TRIED:

```
ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%MIKE%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(Name) * 100 ,1)) AS Percentage_of_MIKE,
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just use [SAFE_DIVIDE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#safe_divide) function in such cases

Something like in below example

```
ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(CASE WHEN Name LIKE '%MIKE%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), COUNT(Name) * 100) ,1) AS Percentage_of_MIKE
```

Comment: added on post what i have tried (can refer above). still get error.

Comment: what you tried (at least what is in your updated question) is not what in my answer - please double check. but obviously, you wrongly applied SAFE_DIVIDE function. it has two arguments. in the way how you applied it  - you still have first argument that does plain divide  on zero! just copy paste my example line and replace yours

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use `NULLIF()` for this purpose, because I like using the division operator for division:

```
SELECT User_ID, 
       ROUND(COUNTIF(Name LIKE '%MIKE%') * 100 / NULLIF(COUNT(Name), 0), 1) AS Percentage_of_MIKE
FROM table
GROUP BY User_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that you have `User_ID`s whose all `Name`s are `NULL`. So the denominator of your division is `0` (`COUNT(Name)` counts non-`null` values of `Name`), and you get the division by `0` error.

A simple way to avoid this is to use `AVG()`:

```
ROUND(AVG(CASE 
    WHEN Name LIKE '%MIKE%' THEN 1.0
    WHEN Name IS NOT NULL THEN 0
END) * 100, 1) AS Percentage_of_MIKE
```

Comment: @swm: welcome. I suspect that `AVG()` is more efficient than other solutions, since it involves just one aggregate function (while other solutions require 2).